# Should a service started as part of an application be visible/killable from the UI?

Tags: android, service, visibility

I'm teaching myself to develop in Android using the sample notes, and documentation.

Here is what I did

- Created an application in a project
- Created a class that extends IntentService in the same project; default implementatin in onHandleIntent
- In the app manifest XML, defined the IntentService child to be subordinate to the application

The application object is visible under App Settings in the emulator. The Service is not visible under either the Application Settings, or the Running Services.

Should the running service be visible independently?

Answer (score 0):

If your app can function without the service running, you should consider enabling the user to change the behaviour of it in the preferences activity of your app.

A service should not be visible by the user in any other means than being able to turn it off or changing the frequency of i.g. network activity.

Comment: Ah. This is a training app I'm trying to write to teach myself to write an Android Service. So my service should be visible under the Running Services if it is configured correctly then?

Comment: The 2.3 emulator should have a setting for showing processes in the cache.